# Nothings happen after I fire the onclick event

Tags: php, html, jquery

Newbie in jquery here: When I click my submit button I expect that it will echo something but It did not. I don't know whats wrong in my code. Please help

Here's my js

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            function add_contact(){
            $.post( "add.php", { 
                "name": $("#txtName").val(),
                "contact": $("#txtContact").val(),
                "email": $("txtEmail").val()
                }, 
                function(msg){
                    $("#message").html(msg);
            });
            return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Here's my html

```
    <label for="txtName">Name</label>
                    <input id="txtName" type="text">
                <label for="txtContact">Contact Number</label>
                    <input id="txtContact" type="text">
                <label for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
                    <input id="txtEmail" type="text">
                <label id="message"></label>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return add_contact()">
```

Here's my add.php

```
        <?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['contact'])&&isset($_POST['email'])){
        echo 'Good';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what do you see in your javascript console?

Comment: do you mean the console from shift+ctrl+j?

Comment: If you use most modern browsers, bring up the "net" tab in the debug console, and watch what happens after you click your button.  Do you see the post occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing a # sign !

```
"email": $("txtEmail").val()
```

change it to

```
"email": $("#txtEmail").val()
```

Comment: also I recommend add a else structure to your add.php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
onclick="add_contact();"
```

instead of

```
onclick="return add_contact()"
```

[EDIT:]

I whipped up a little jsfiddle of the situation, and modified your code a little bit. check out http://jsfiddle.net/Pbf2T/16/

Here is the JS

```
$(function(){
    var add_contact = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "add.php",
            data: {
                "name": $("#txtName").val(),
                "contact": $("#txtContact").val(),
                "email": $("#txtEmail").val()           
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success");
                $("#message").html(data);
            },
            error: function(x,t,error) {
                alert("error: " + error);
                console.log(error);                
            }            
        })
    }


    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        add_contact();
    })
})
```

If you try this, please reply with the error you see.

[EDIT2:] ok, please try the above, and report back. In the success handler, I typo-ed the returned data.
​

Comment: @BrainedWashed the edited version should tell you what the error is.

Comment: @BrainedWashed I had an incorrectly named variable left in the success handler. It is now fixed. try again?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have quotes around the data you send via post, i.e. instead of `"name": $("#txtName").val()`, it should just be `name: $("#txtName").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

try with type="button" instead of submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return add_contact()">
```

as you using ajax for your submit.